# "x is not defined error" while eval(python-expression)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, eval

This is what I'm trying to do -

```
expr = "x==1"

var = "x"


def func(var,expr):

    num_list =[0,1,2]
    for y in num_list:
        var = y
        if eval(constraint):
           print("true")
```

Comment: I know the error is coming becasue x is undefined for the eval expression. But i cannot hardcode x and initialize it. The expression could have any variable x,y or z in the expression which is known to us via 'var' varibale

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `var` with `x` such as,

```
expr = "x+1"
x = "x"

def func(var,expr):

    num_list =[0,1,2]
    for y in num_list:
        x = y
        if eval(expr):
           print("true")

func(x,expr)
```

output:

```
true
true
true
```